missing createRequest on Remix value not defined
I try to do a simple login from Remix. I inspire myself from https://remix.run/docs/en/main/discussion/pending-ui.
I want to do a simple login system just to try without no database, but when I launch the script I have got the missing createRequest.
import {
  ActionFunction,
  redirect,
  ActionFunctionArgs
} from "@remix-run/node"
import { Form, useActionData, } from "@remix-run/react";
import {createRequest } from "run/node";

export async function action({ request, }: ActionFunctionArgs) {
    const formData = await request.formData();
    const project = await ccreateRequest({
         username:formData.get("username"),
         password: formData.get("password"),
    });
    if (project.username === "admin" && project.password === "password") {
        // Redirect to the dashboard or home page after login
        return redirect("/dashboard");
    }
    return {
        errorMessage: "Invalid username or password",
    };
}

Could you help me to find the dependance for createRequest?

there's no such function createRequest. The example code that you shared in the link uses createRecord, which is some custom function you should be creating that processes the submitted data (could be inserting to database), in your case, you could just do:
import { ActionFunction, redirect,ActionFunctionArgs } from "@remix-run/node"
import { Form, useActionData, } from "@remix-run/react";
// import {createRequest } from "run/node"; //this does not exist

export async function action({request,}: ActionFunctionArgs) {
    const formData = await request.formData();

    // get username and password from formData
    const username = formData.get("username");
    const password = formData.get("password");

    if (username  === "admin" && password === "password") {
        // Redirect to the dashboard or home page after login
        return redirect("/dashboard");
    }
    return {
        errorMessage: "Invalid username or password",
    };
}

